# php array split

Tags: php, arrays, split

- I am passing the space separated value to in input and split this in operation and make an array.

> givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y

- But i want to pass the message in this string and want to split as complete message in operation or output.

> givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y hi how are
>   you

if i split this line than i get the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => givecard
    [1] => 442
    [2] => ashutosh2
    [3] => Y
    [4] => hi
    [5] => how
    [6] => are
    [7] => you
)
```

But i want like this

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => givecard
        [1] => 442
        [2] => ashutosh2
        [3] => Y
        [4] => hi how are you 
    )
```

as here hi how are you i want to extract as complete one message in a variable .
How can i achieve this

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you make an example of the desired output?

Comment: what is the characteristic that defines that "hi how are you" should not be split? The Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
preg_split('/\s+/', "givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y hi how are you", 5);
```

---

Say you have a function like so:

```
function operate_on_string($string) {
    $out = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);

    # ...
    return $out;
}
```

- Option one:

Pass the string "givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y" and have "hi how are you" appended to the end of it:

```
operate_on_string("givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y" . ' ' . "hi how are you");
```

- Option two:

Just pass the first string to it, then append the rest to the output:

```
array_merge(operate_on_string("givecard 442 ashutosh2 Y"), preg_split('/\s+/', "hi how are you"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From your problem, I guess it's a preformatted string.
Let me see, can you use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$format = explode(" ", $data, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, is it possible to separate values by smt else? For example:

givecard:442:ashutosh2:Y:hi how are you

and then explode it on :